# Relay Mail from an application to Gmail through ssmtp

Tags: linux, smtp, ssmtp

i want make my linux server to receive mail from an host (LAN but if possible through Internet) and than relay to Gmail.

I made the second part with ssmtp let the server send mail through Gmail using

```
ssmtp email@address.com < msg.txt
```

The other part is needed for example for use program that integrate some smtp alarm function.
The majority of this program doesn't support sending with credential so i need to pass through a server that doesn't need it.

The final result must be:

> Host_with_smtp_alarm_function   ->   server_smtp   ->   Gmail_server

How can i make this work?

**EDIT:**

My host have a mask to fill with smtp server info.
Filling with ip and port resulting in a "impossible to connect"
The linux server are not listening for a connection, so send but not receive.

`netstat -a` confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not clear:

If you wish send e-mail to google - it's completly enought to set alias in postfix pointed to google account. For example:

```
account: account@gmail.com
```

It will forward any mail sent to account@$localdomail to account@gmail.com

Alternativly - if you wish forward e-mail via google (you wish to send e-mail to internet using gmail account, but to to gmail) - you must configure smtp authentication. Example for postfix are on http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_enable

Comment: add edit on the post

Comment: Resolved using postfix.
Thank you!